# I try to run some samples in VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio

> Error 1   It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.  C:\Users\rzv\Desktop\WebSamples\Backup\WebSamples\Web.config    49

when I try to run http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx in VS 2010. What's wrong and why do I get IIS error when I run something in VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

When you convert a project from VS 2008 to VS 2010, it creates a folder /backup/ inside of the application.  When you run the project, it is trying to run the project and the subfolder /backup/, which contains a `web.config` file.  Move the /backup/ folder to another location and it should work.

In general, you can't run an application from a subfolder of another application if it uses application-level settings in its configuration file `web.config`.

Comment: I've oppened the solution file. And hit RUN. what do you suggest I should change?

Comment: @Ryan: Hmm.  I dunno, checking it out myself now.  That's generally what that error means.

Comment: @Ryan: I have reproduced the issue and edited my answer with the solution.